# CSS: Font color wont change

Tags: css, fonts, colors

I have a problem with my html file not using a font color defined in a CSS stylesheet. It seems to be partly working but it unfortunately doesn't do what I want it to do.

```css
* {
  font-family: "verdana"
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bodytop {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  background-image: url(images/header.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #444444;
}

.bodybottom {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.buttonbox {
  display: table;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #888888;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<htmL>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <!--Header, the first 250px from the top-->
      <div class=bodytop>
        <!--upper part of the website-->
        <center>
          <div class="buttonbox">
            Dit is button3
          </div>
          <div class="buttonbox">
            Dit is button2
          </div>
          <div class="buttonbox">
            Dit is button1
          </div>
        </center>
        <div class=bodybottom>
          <!--Lower part of the website-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</htmL>
```

The code seems to be working as the font is changed to Verdana but the color won't change.

Comment: Don't use `<center>` tag. It died when the dinosaurs died.

Comment: Yes I figured xD, I do know I need to change this but since I don´t know exactly how I used this quickly to check how it would look however that´s going to change. Removing this will not help with the font color tho. I didn´t want to ask this question in this same topic since I haven´t let my proper researching skills loose on it. But thanks for the heads up ^^.

Comment: That was just a funny joke. Other than that the issue is of missing semicolon on the first line buddy!

Comment: K, now I'm just ashamed >,<. That solves the problem =D. Thank you so much and I'm so sorry for wasting your time like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of specificity. You have set `color` for `*`, the universal selector. For specific elements you need to set the colour. Moreover, there's only one `color`, which is in the universal selector.

Also, your CSS has errors:

```
font-family: "verdana"
//--------------------^ No Semi colon.
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "verdana"; /* Corrected */
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bodytop {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  background-image: url(images/header.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #444444;
}

.bodybottom {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.buttonbox {
  display: table;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #888888;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I see, then should I define the color within the wrapper div? Or do you have another suggestion for me?

Comment: @RobertWiedeman Don't define a few things in the `*`. That's all. Esp. `color`, `width`, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semi-colon after your font-family:

```css
*{
  font-family: "verdana"; /* Missing this semi-colon. */
  color: #FFF;
}
.wrapper
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.header
{
  display: table;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.bodytop
{
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  background-image: url(images/header.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #444444;
}
.bodybottom
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #666666;
}
.buttonbox
{
  display: table;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #888888;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
<!--Header, the first 250px from the top-->
    <div class=bodytop>
    <!--upper part of the website-->
        <center>
        <div class="buttonbox">
        Dit is button3
        </div>
        <div class="buttonbox">
        Dit is button2
        </div>
        <div class="buttonbox">
        Dit is button1
        </div>
        </center>
    <div class=bodybottom>
    <!--Lower part of the website-->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your CSS is missing a semi-colon, it should be:

```
* {
    font-family: "verdana";
    color: #FFF;
}
```